# Query Logic - Finding current/previous states of work items

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem

I need to run a query in TFS to determine if a specific action occurred on a Work Item during a specific time frame.

For example, I want to view all work items that have been marked 'Failed Test' in the last week.

I can't just add "State = Failed Test" because the work item may no longer be in 'Failed Test' status (it could have been Fixed at this point).  What I need is "State was Failed Test at any point during this date range".

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with Work Item Queries, but you can do this query against the TFS Data Warehouse using SQL (e.g. inside a custom SSRS report).

PS - I believe the tables you want are FactWorkItemHistory and DimWorkItem (from the Tfs_Warehouse database)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Was Ever` operator to check if a field had some value in the past. Your WIQL query will look like this:

`SELECT [System.Id], [System.Title] 
FROM WorkItems 
WHERE [System.TeamProject] = @project 
AND  [System.State] EVER 'Failed Test' 
AND  [System.ChangedDate] IN (@today -1, @today - 2, @today -3, @today -4, @today -5, @today -6, @today -7) 
ORDER BY [System.Id]`